# How to force a React component to re-render based on the attribute of a JS object?

Tags: reactjs, object, attributes, components

I'm building a music app in ReactJS.

I have a playlist that contains tracks (which are object instances of my custom class *TrackObj*).

When a track is clicked, I make an API call to get some datas; via my *TrackObj* function *getTrackDatas()*.

That function updates the **_isApiRequest** attribute of my *TrackObj* item :

```
export default class TrackObj {
  ...
  async getTrackDatas() {
    const track = this;
    track._isApiRequest = true;
    console.log("TRACK APIREQUEST 1",track._isApiRequest);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Api.request(config)
      .then(function(datas){
        ...
        resolve(datas);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        ...
        reject(err);
      })
      .finally(function(){
        track._isApiRequest = false;
        console.log("TRACK APIREQUEST 2",track._isApiRequest);
      })
    }
    })
  }
  ...
}
```

Now, I want to "link" that attribute to my React Track component :

```
playlist.tracks.map((track,key) => {
  return (
    <li
    key={key}
    >
      <Track
      track={track}
      apiLoading={track._isApiRequest}
      />
    </li>
  )
})
```

But that doesn't work.

I also made an attempt by using a useEffect directly in my Track component :

```
export const Track = (props) => {

  const track = props.track;
  const [apiLoading,setApiLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setApiLoading(track._isApiRequest);
  }, [track._isApiRequest]);

  ...

}
```

It doesn't update the *apiLoading* state correctly either.

I guess there is something I don't get about re-rendering items.

How could make this work ?

Thanks !

Comment: By default, components re-render when their state or props change (or when their parent re-renders). If the changing of a value needs to cause a re-render, that value should be in state. So put the loading status into state, then when changing it the component will re-render

Comment: That what I did in my second attempt (see bottom of my question); and it is not working...

Comment: Adding to what @Jayce444 said, try to ensure the parent render function is running by putting _isApiLoading in the state. That will run the render function and the children will be rendered with new props.

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: @gordie yes but in that second attempt you put a property of the `track` prop as a dependency. So unless that prop changes, that effect won't get run, and if it doesn't get run then the `apiLoading` state won't be changed, and thus re-rendering won't occur (which is why I'm guessing that approach still isn't working). Are you able to recreate a sandbox of this just using dummy data to mimic the API stuff

Comment: @Jayce444 : but the prop of my track object IS changing, the console output (see `getTrackDatas()` is correctly printed (TRUE then FALSE); but the state of the Track component isn't updated. -- EDIT : I had a typo in my question, fixed it.

Comment: Here's a demo : http://v2test.spiff-radio.org/radio/278325